# How do the Incredibles put on their suits?

Tags: the-incredibles, incredibles-2

The Incredibles' super suits are one-piece, so how do they put them on? Do they have to stick their bodies feet-first through the neck hole? Is there a hidden zipper somewhere?

Comment: Is there something in *Incredibles 2* that categorically shows the suits *are one piece?*  (I haven't seen I2 yet, and I don't recall anything suggesting this in I1.)  A two piece spandex suit (shirt and pants) *can* look like one piece while worn, especially when there's a belt, which these suits have.

Comment: @Steve-O The suits are pretty obviously one-piece. When the kids are throwing them around (in *Incredibles 2*), they're one single piece of fabric... that doesn't mean there's not a hidden zipper somewhere, though.

Comment: In I2 (in the trailers no not a spoiler), Violet holds up her suit as a one-piece, and throws it into the garbage disposal (where it does not get damaged). So we can confirm that at the very least, hers is a one-piece. So it is safe to assume that others have one-piece costumes as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems clear that Edna Mode designs suits for each person individually and caters for individual requirements. However, there is no confirmation that **any** suit is actually *only* one-piece...but the available evidence is that they are.

When held up they appear as one solid item of clothing.

[image]

However, most notable is the suit for Elastigirl

> Your suit can stretch as far as you can, without injuring 
>   yourself, and still retain its shape. Virtually indestructible...yet it 
>   breathes like Egyptian cotton
>
> <sup>[Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Incredibles,-The.html)</sup>

So, it seems likely that each suit will stretch as much as is needed to put it on and then shrink back to be form fitting as we see.

We know that Bob's *old* suit was one-piece but stretched up considerably when he wore it so we must assume the new suit is the same.

Note the size when he holds it in his hand:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this based on *The Incredibles*.

They wear it just like every other superhero. It is just fabric but of an advanced type.

Mr. Incredible has it covered by his regular clothes. See the ending scene of *The Incredibles*.

Violet's suit is invisible when it comes to contact with her body. So, we can assume that she becomes invisible and changes her clothes.

Helen changes her suit like changing clothes. It is shown in *The Incredibles* where she goes to a changing room to change her suit.

They put the masks on when there is a need to fight by taking them out of their pockets.

Comment: I think by "dress" you might mean "clothes"? Generally "dress" refers to a specific type of women's clothing. "Clothes" means what everyone wears.

Comment: Also it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I think you've sort of missed what the question is asking here... your answer discusses the fact that they wear their suits under their day clothes but the question is asking how do they actually get into the suit in the first place. Being invisible or changing in a changing room doesn't really explain *how* they get into it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yes, I mean the clothes.

Comment: @Catija Not everyone are wearing the suits under the clothes. Only Bob does it. It's not explained how they wear it. Regarding how they they put their heads into it, I added a single line which isn't suffice. Each suit's fabric is designed advanced. Lemme add some quotes from the movie. It takes some time. Paulie_D added an answer similar to what I thought. But I will add them anyway.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Well... In some dialects (many of them formal) it means something analogous to "the clothes that are being worn", e.g. "evening dress" meaning the clothes you wear in the evening. I read this with its expected meaning, so I can attest that it sounded normal enough to me (though not when I critically analyse it for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

May be they are like the spiderman suit from Spiderman homecoming.. you get in the dress and it fits to your body size.
[image]